# Multiple User Control Process Class sharing base control access

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a layered winform application.

I have a base class, example as below :-

```
public class UPCBase{

   public TextBox txtUsername {set;get;}

}
```

and I have 2 UPC class that inheric UPCBase

```
public class UPCA : UPCBase{
   public void someMethod(){
      string _a = txtUsername.Text;
   }
}

public class UPCB : UPCBase{
   public void someMethod(){
      string _b = txtUsername.Text;
   }
}
```

I'm currently struggling with the hassle of have to reassign txtUsername to the class of UPCA and UPCB on Winform code-behind

```
UPCA.txtUsername = usernameTextBox;
UPCB.txtUsername = usernameTextBox;
```

is there a way that I can achieve I assigned once to and re-using it whenever I call UPC until the user close the application?

My initial stage was putting `public TextBox txtUsername {set;get;}` in both UPCA and UPCB but that adds to more area of code to maintain, therefore I decided to use a UPCBase instead.

Can someone shared some lights how to achieve this?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by: "is there a way that I can achieve I assigned once to and re-using it whenever I call UPC"

Comment: @MongZhu

for example, 

I can just assign it once `<something>.txtUsername = usernameTextBox;`

and whenever I call `UPCA.somemethod()` or `UPCB.somemethod()` the reference to txtUSername is there.

Comment: I think in this case you have to declare `txtUsername` as static in you base class.